# How to get certain elements of an array using an inline condition C#?

Tags: c#, inline, conditional-operator

I am currently learning Object Orientated Programming in C#, and as such, am just playing around with classes trying to create a game.

In the game I am making currently, I have a Warrior class, that has a method, Attack(), that has two overloads, `public void Attack(Warrior enemy)` as well as `public void Attack(params Warrior[] enemies)`.

Using the first overload is fine, I instantiate two Warrior objects in Program.cs, and use a while loop that continues until one of the warriors is dead, choosing who attacks at each time based on a random number generator.

```
Random random = new Random();

Warrior warrior1 = new Warrior("Ben", Faction.GoodGuy);
Warrior warrior2 = new Warrior("Alfie", Faction.BadGuy);

while (warrior1.IsAlive && warrior2.IsAlive)
{
    if (random.Next(9) < 5)
    {
        warrior1.Attack(warrior2);
    }
    else
    {
        warrior2.Attack(warrior1);
    }
}
```

However, my problem arises when I try to use the second overload, with mulitiple enemies.

I create four enemies, and start the while loop, as shown below.

```
Random random = new Random();
Warrior warrior1 = new Warrior("Ben", Faction.GoodGuy);
Warrior warrior2 = new Warrior("Alfie", Faction.BadGuy);
Warrior warrior3 = new Warrior("Joel", Faction.BadGuy);
Warrior warrior4 = new Warrior("Ruben", Faction.GoodGuy);

while(warrior1.IsAlive || warrior2.IsAlive || warrior3.IsAlive || warrior4.IsAlive)
{
    Warrior[] warriors = new Warrior[] { warrior1, warrior2, warrior3, warrior4 };

    switch (random.Next(4))
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

On each case, I want a warrior to attack every other warrior that is currently alive.

So on case 0: warrior 1 attacks all other alive warriors

on case 1: warrior 2 attacks all other warriors

on case 2: warrior 3 attacks all other warriors

on case 3: warrior 4 attacks all other warriors

I could quite easily do this with a foreach loop, but I was wondering, in the interest of cleaner code and writing less code, if there was a way to do this inline. I have seen people use the ? operator for this sort of thing, but I am not sure exactly how to use it, or if it even applies here.

I would appreciate it if you could help me with the inline operator, if there is indeed one.

Thanks, Ben

***My code if you should need it:***

Program.Cs

```
using System;

namespace Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            Warrior warrior1 = new Warrior("Ben", Faction.GoodGuy);
            Warrior warrior2 = new Warrior("Alfie", Faction.BadGuy);

            /*while (warrior1.IsAlive && warrior2.IsAlive)
            {
                if (random.Next(9) < 5)
                {
                    warrior1.Attack(warrior2);
                }
                else
                {
                    warrior2.Attack(warrior1);
                }
            }*/

            Warrior warrior3 = new Warrior("Joel", Faction.BadGuy);
            Warrior warrior4 = new Warrior("Ruben", Faction.GoodGuy);

            while(warrior1.IsAlive || warrior2.IsAlive || warrior3.IsAlive || warrior4.IsAlive)
            {
                Warrior[] warriors = new Warrior[] { warrior1, warrior2, warrior3, warrior4 };

                switch (random.Next(4))
                {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("End of Code");
        }
    }
}
```

Warrior.cs

```
namespace Game
{
    class Warrior
    {
        private const double GOOD_GUY_HEALTH = 100;
        private const double BAD_GUY_HEALTH = 100;

        public double Health { get; set; }
        public bool IsAlive { get; set; } = true;

        private string name;
        private Faction faction;
        private Weapon weapon;
        private Armour armour;

        public Warrior(string name, Faction faction)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.faction = faction;

            switch (faction)
            {
                case Faction.GoodGuy:
                    Health = GOOD_GUY_HEALTH;
                    weapon = new Weapon(faction);
                    armour = new Armour(faction);
                    break;
                case Faction.BadGuy:
                    Health = BAD_GUY_HEALTH;
                    weapon = new Weapon(faction);
                    armour = new Armour(faction);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void Attack(Warrior enemy)
        {
            System.Random random = new System.Random();
            double attackDamage = random.Next((int)System.Math.Ceiling(weapon.Damage)) - random.Next((int)System.Math.Ceiling(enemy.armour.ArmourPoints));

            if (attackDamage < 0)
            {
                attackDamage = 0;
            }

            enemy.Health -= attackDamage;

            if (enemy.Health <= 0)
            {
                enemy.Health = 0;
                enemy.IsAlive = false;
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("{0} deals {1} damage. {2} is on {3} health", this.name, attackDamage, enemy.name, enemy.Health);

            if (enemy.IsAlive == false)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} is dead, {1} is victorious!", enemy.name, this.name);
            }
        }

        public void Attack(params Warrior[] enemies)
        {
            System.Random random = new System.Random();
            double damageLeft = weapon.Damage;

            for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++)
            {
                if (damageLeft <= 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                double damageBeforeShield = random.NextDouble() * System.Math.Ceiling(damageLeft / enemies.Length);
                double attackDamage = damageBeforeShield - (random.NextDouble() * enemies[i].armour.ArmourPoints);

                damageLeft -= attackDamage;

                if (enemies[i].Health < 0)
                {
                    enemies[i].Health = 0;
                    enemies[i].IsAlive = false;
                }

                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} deals {1} damage. {2} is on {3} helath", this.name, attackDamage, enemies[i].name, enemies[i].Health);

                if (enemies[i].IsAlive == false)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} is dead, {1} is victorious!", enemies[i].name, this.name);
                }




            }
        }

    }
}
```

Faction.cs

```
namespace Game
{
    enum Faction
    {
        GoodGuy, BadGuy
    }
}
```

Weapon.cs

```
namespace Game
{
    class Weapon
    {
        private double damage;

        public double Damage
        {
            get
            {
                return damage;
            }
        }

        public Weapon(Faction faction)
        {
            switch (faction)
            {
                case Faction.GoodGuy:
                    damage = 20;
                    break;
                case Faction.BadGuy:
                    damage = 20;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Armour.cs

```
namespace Game
{
    class Armour
    {
        private readonly double armourPoints;

        public double ArmourPoints
        {
            get
            {
                return armourPoints;
            }
        }

        public Armour(Faction faction)
        {
            switch (faction)
            {
                case Faction.GoodGuy:
                    armourPoints = 20;
                    break;
                case Faction.BadGuy:
                    armourPoints = 20;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very nice application for studying purpose, you are doing great!

You can use RemoveAt method of List. I don't see a reason in switch there, so it will be quite simple:

```
while(warrior1.IsAlive || warrior2.IsAlive || warrior3.IsAlive || warrior4.IsAlive)
{
    var warriors = new List<Warrior> { warrior1, warrior2, warrior3, warrior4 };
    ProcessAttacks(warriors, random.Next(4));
}
```

And here is ProcessAttacks function:

```
private void ProcessAttacks(List<Warrior> warriors, int currentWarrior)
{
    var warrior = warriors[currentWarrior];
    warriors.RemoveAt(currentWarrior);
    warrior.Attack(warriors);
}
```

Also it will require changing signature of you `public void Attack(params Warrior[] enemies)` to `public void Attack(List<Warrior> enemies)`

Comment: I guess only one thing is missing in `ProcessAttacks()`, after `Attack()` method we should I add `currentWarrior` again because he is still alive. Correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: if you mean adding warrior back to List then no, we don't need to do that because on the next loop cycle List is recreated again with all 4.

Comment: yeah, I did not notice it.